# Differential query - valid deltaLink now giving "Bad Request"

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm performing a differential query against Azure AD, and a deltaLink that I have been using for a couple of months is now (as of the last few days) returning "Bad Request" when presented.

No code changes, other deltaLink work fine, so I'm pretty sure it's not code related.

Is there a reason for this - e.g. do differential query deltaLinks expire? I can't find any documentation saying they do.

Comment: Just to be sure we're talking about the same thing--is the "token" you speak of the [`deltaLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-differential-query#url-query-string-parameters)?

Comment: Thanks for responding Philippe, yes, it's the deltaLink

Comment: Can you please provide the request-id (part of response headers) and a timestamp? We can investigate further.

Comment: Perhaps a silly question: were you using the *same* `deltaLink` you got two months ago? Or were you updating with the latest `deltaLink`/`nextLink` that you would get each time you used one?

Comment: The very same one, I've been using it fairly regularly for testing over the last couple of months, when suddenly... "Bad Request"

Comment: Interesting. As @Pavan asked in his "answer", can you share the `request-id` (it'll be in the response headers) and a timestamp for that request?

Comment: Thanks: request-id: 55c3f83a-4d21-4d3f-974d-5fdfc25c6061
Date: Tue, 07 Jun 2016 19:27:39 GMT